# iOS 15 Safari scroll bug, black block at the end of the page when keyboard is open

Tags: ios, scroll, safari

When some field in focus and keyboard is open you can scroll until the end of page and a little more, there is a black block at the end of the page, which is not part of DOM.
Important note: urlbar should be at the bottom. When urlbar on top there is no problem.

Example on codepen in full mode to reproduce
https://codepen.io/iceblink/yLPpVQo

```
<input type="text"> // when some field focus and keyboard open
```

iPhone 12, iOS 15.2 / iPhone 11 pro max, iOS 14.2 / iPhone 11, iOS 15.3.1 – all have the same strange behavior.
Androids don't have any problems.

[Screenshot ios simulator with bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FDnx.jpg)